# Redisearch query with partial match

Tags: redisearch

I'm encountering a little issue with the FT.SEARCH command from redisearch:

For this data whose value is this one: `ns=2;s=OIGateway:ArchestrA.ACU.AO_ACU230_AIn_CabTp.fa_A2OutOfRan`

How come this query:

```
FT.SEARCH index 'ns 2 s oigateway archestra acu ao_acu230_ain_cabtp fa_a2o* '
```

Will return the result

Whereas this one:

```
FT.SEARCH index 'ns 2 s oigateway archestra acu ao_acu230_ain_cabtp fa_a2* '
```

(Notice the missing 'o' at the end)

Will return nothing?

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

The second query should return all the results from the first one, or more since the prefix might include more results.

Can it be the fact that the first query runs on `index` while the second runs on `glossary`.

Comment: I edited the question. But I learnt that redisearch doesn't allow partial search at all.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up learning that redisearch doesn't allow partial search (I mean not like the partial search in sql database LIKE '%hello%')